# Find the approximation of the following definite integral given a value of n

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

So I have an integral

$$\int_0^2\frac{x}{(x+1)}$$

and the value of $n$ is $n = 5$

I know the answer is $\frac{127}{140} = 0,9071$

However I have no idea how they got to that answer. I Have a feeling we are learning about the transition of reimann sums to definite integrals, but I really don't get what i'm supposed to do...

Comment: Have you noticed you didn't write what is $\;n\;$ and we still cannot guess?

Comment: If you are transitioning from Reimann Sums to Definite Integrals, then here's how to start: Saying $n=5$ means you want 5 rectangles of equal width going from the values 0 to 2. So the width of each rectangle would be $0.4$